# How can I use the a object property using single variable?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var game: () => {
    board: (firstRun: any) => void;
    place: (position: any, letter: any) => void;
    newGame: () => void;
}

var ticTacToe = game();
```

for me to execute the move for my console base tictactoe I need to enter

```
ticTacToe.place(position, "X")
```

But what I want to do is to execute it in single variable so instead of that I want it to be like

```
move(position, "X") or move(1, "X")
```

Comment: `const move = ticTacToe.place`?

Comment: We can't tell you without knowing what the *implementation* of `game` is. All you've shown us above is its type. @JeremyThille's suggestion above might work, if `place` is a bound function or only uses things it closes over, or equally it may not work if those things aren't true. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (You can also include a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) for the TS parts.)

Comment: if this is typescript, please add the tag

Comment: tictactoe.js:133 Uncaught TypeError: this.drawBoard is not a function
    at place (tictactoe.js:133)
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: im sorry guys I'm fairly new to this :(s

Comment: I hope this can help

https://codepen.io/cobautista/pen/poNawjG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a move variable refer the place method:

```
let move = (place,token) => ticTacToe.place(place,token);
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
move(1,"x");
```

Comment: Yeah i changed it to arrow function (no need for binding with arrow function)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make functions for each action. Something like this:

```
function move(position, letter){
ticTacToe.place(position,letter)
}
```

So you can call them just like you want to:

```
move(1, "X");
move(2, "O");
...etc.
```

Comment: you're welcome :) good luck with your coding and please consider using `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: I will, one more follow up question, I assume you saw the code, I just want to ask if I can add a function which can show the previous step on the board? not necessary rewind like showing move history or something like that.  I'm trying to understand the deep copy but I'm having a hard time applying that to my code.

Comment: do you wanna store it somewhere in like one variable or just have it displayed each time you make a move?